# i th order statistic in Python

Tags: python

Given a list of `n` comparable elements (say numbers or string), the optimal algorithm to find the `i`th ordered element takes `O(n)` time.

Does Python implement natively `O(n)` time order statistics for lists, dicts, sets, ...?

Comment: Would appreciate a comment from the downvoter and closevoter.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

None of Python's mentioned data structures implements natively the ith order statistic algorithm.

In fact, it might not make much sense for dictionaries and sets, given the fact that both make no assumptions about the ordering of its elements. For lists, it shouldn't be hard to implement the [selection algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_algorithm), which provides O(n) running time.

Answer (score 6):

This is not a native solution, but you can use NumPy's [partition](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.partition.html#numpy.partition) to find the *k*-th order statistic of a list in O(n) time.

```
import numpy as np
x = [2, 4, 0, 3, 1]
k = 2
print('The k-th order statistic is:', np.partition(np.asarray(x), k)[k])
```

EDIT: this assumes zero-indexing, i.e. the "zeroth order statistic" above is `0`.

Comment: This is not accurate.  After partitioning, you need to find the maximum.  So this `np.partition(np.asarray(x), k)[:k].max()`

Comment: @piRSquared, thanks. I think you interpreted it as 1-indexed, so I've now clarified that.

Comment: My point is that `np.partition` is not sorting.  That's the point of it and why it's better.  That said, because it isn't sorted, there is no guarantee that the kth order statistic is in the kth position.  I'm not referring to zero or one based indexing.  I'm referring to the fact that sometimes your solution will produce the incorrect answer.  Suppose I wanted the 5th order statistic from a randomly shuffled set of integers from 0 to 36.  Your answer produces `1` with my example here: `np.random.seed(0); np.partition(np.random.permutation(np.arange(37)), 5)[4]`.  And the answer should be `4`.

Comment: In order to correct for this, you need to find the maximum over the first k elements.  `np.random.seed(0); np.partition(np.random.permutation(np.arange(37)), 5)[:5].max()`

Comment: @piRSquared, in your example, the 0th order statistic is `0`, and the 5th order statistic is `5`.  Try doing:  `np.partition(np.random.permutation(np.arange(37)), 5)[5]` and you will get the correct answer of `5`.  You are correct `np.partition` does not sort, but one thing it does do is guarantee that `5` is in the 5th spot.

Answer (score 1):

If i << n you can give a look at http://docs.python.org/library/heapq.html#heapq.nlargest and http://docs.python.org/library/heapq.html#heapq.nsmallest (the don't solve your problem, but are faster than sorting and taking the i-th element).